# Neurotransmitter stimulation, ownership, and the right to bring into existence with pleasure

Tags: rights

I wanted to ask, if looking or thinking with a person releases the right neurotransmitter combinations, that, with the passing of time, takes you, to the right, developments, or actions

then does that mean that person has a right to bash, whatever, and to whatever is produced by the other person's brain, with those looks, thoughts, or actions.

Thank you.

Comment: I have no clue what is being asked in this question. Can someone clarify for me?

Answer (score 1):

It has often crossed my mind, as I wander through the throngs of enthralled onlookers who are enraptured by my wondrous appearance, that I would be a billionaire all over again if I had the right to charge them for the experience. However, in most countries individuals are free to gather through their eyes whatever photons happen to come their way, and through their ears whatever sounds, so you do not have the right to charge them for the experience per se. What you can do, of course, is charge them to enter cinemas, buy books, and so on, but that is a different legal principle.

Comment: I always found it mystifying that the BBC thought they could charge for *over the air* television.